# Ionic App POST/PUT/DELETE/GET method(s) response capture and display

Tags: php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a beginner and learning for example to submit a form to create an order (using POST method), edit an order (using PUT method), delete an order (using DELETE method) or search for an order (using GET method) targeting a restful web service. The order info is captured by the server script (probably PHP) and depending on the http method the order is either inserted, updated or deleted respectively. I have no knowledge of how the script does it.

My 2 questions are:

1. when I POST, PUT or DELETE, the server script could successfully perform the operation on the database (or) be unsuccessful in making changes to the database. How will I know if the script performed the database operation successfully or failed or there was some other error so that I can display a status to the user of the app accordingly?

(I understand that for a GET request the script sends the data requested in JSON or XML and I need to parse the JSON and display it to the app user. I just dont understand how it works for POST, PUT or DELETE. Will I receive a json for info or should I look somewhere else to able to provide a useful response to the app user).

2. I see POST being used instead of GET to get JSON response. My understanding is that POST is for insert operation only. Am I missing something? Why POST is being used in real time sometimes.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When the script finishes you send back a status code (200 is okay, 500-Internal server error, 404-Not found etc) and a message (json in your case)
2. "I see POST being used instead of GET to get JSON response", depends on what type of processing you are referring to. If you need a resource (a specific entity) you make a GET request, but if you need to make a custom process or a search then POST might be good for you

P.S: A good read on implementing a [API](https://www.sitepoint.com/best-practices-rest-api-scratch-introduction/) an [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340). Check out the status codes used in the example, you can change your implementation based on your needs

Comment: Thank you for the response! Just one more quick question.....for your response to 1. Let us say the insert or update or delete operation is successful and the script sends a status code of 200. In addition to that will a json message also be sent with info that it was a success which the ionic app developer must use (or) is it just the status code. I am not refering to a GET request during which I understand you get a JSON but POST, PUT or DELETE. Your response will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Depends as well, you can have an empty payload...status 200 means a success so the app should know how to handle this. You could return a json with a message (which will be displayed in the app) but it depends if you want a multi-language app...